# I Can't Boot to Device anymore after flashing wrong boot.img

Tags: samsung, twrp, custom-roms, lineageos, samsung-galaxy-j7

Device Info : Samsung Galaxy J7 (2016) - SM-J710FN INS

I'm Not Able to Boot into System Anymore after flashing `boot.img` from Odin and cannot boot back to system anymore. is there any way to boot into recovery or download mode again?
I've tried `Power + Volume Up + Home` But it just shows me Samsung Logo and no longer proceeds. even when putting phone at charge it stucks at the charging icon and never shows percentage.